# I'm trying to read the text of one of my HTML pages, rather than the HTML that generates it. Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cors, fetch-api

I'm relatively inexperienced with coding for the web, though I have done some basic programming in Python and Java before.

Essentially, I'm trying to get around CORS in a way that is, arguably, stupid, but I couldn't figure out how to make other methods I found online work. So my question is twofold - will my method work if I do it right, and if so, how do I do it right?

Basically, what I want is to read the text from another website as a string onto my website.

My current method, which isn't working, is that I copied the text of the other website onto a page of my website using an iframe, and I'm trying to use the text from that page.

So I have one page, myurl.example/PageOne.html, which is basically just this:

```
    <iframe src="otherurl.example"></iframe>
```

And that successfully replicates the text content of otherurl.example on myurl.example/PageOne.html
And then I have a second page myurl.example/PageTwo.html, where I want to parse the text displayed on PageOne.html. Not the text contained within the html, but the text that the end-user would see. So far I have succeeded in fetching the HTML and printing it to console, but I can't figure out a way to internally "run" the HTML such that I can grab the text and turn it to a string.

```
      fetch('myurl.example/PageOne.html').then(function (response) {

      response.text().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
      })

      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      });
```

^This prints the html of PageOne.html to console, but how do I interact with the text that PageOne.html displays? Is this impossible because of CORS or some other reason, and I should use another method?

Comment: Web browsers protect content between domains unless response headers allow sharing. You cannot "get around" that.

Comment: An iframe doesn't copy the contents of the other web page into your page. The browser processes the iframe tag when rendering, and it gets the other page and renders it inside your page. But `fetch()` doesn't do this, it just fetches the `<iframe>` tag literally.

Comment: To do what you want, implement a proxy on your server that fetches the remote URL.